# Not able to pass the Oldvalue , newValue to HistoryObject Record through test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage, accounthistory

I am not able to insert the newValue and OldValue of Account History record in Test class.
In the below apex class, historyList containes the History object records. when i created account and updated the account record from test class New value and Old Values are coming as null.

Can you please help me how to cover the below logic from test class

Apex Class:

```
public List<objectHistoryLine> getObjectHistory() {
list<sObject> historyList = Database.query('SELECT CreatedDate, CreatedById, Field, NewValue, OldValue ' +
                                           'FROM ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectHistoryTableName) + ' ' +
                                           'WHERE ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(ObjectIdName) + ' = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(myObjectId) +'\' ' +
                                           'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC ' +
                                           'LIMIT ' + String.valueOf(recordLimit));
system.debug('########historyList'+historyList);


for (Integer i = 0; i < historyList.size(); i++) {

    sObject historyLine = historyList.get(i);

    if ((historyLine.get('newValue') == null && historyLine.get('oldValue') == null)
        || (historyLine.get('newValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('00G')))
        || (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('00G')))) {

            objectHistoryLine tempHistory = new objectHistoryLine();

            // Set the Date and who performed the action
            if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate')) != prevDate) {
                tempHistory.theDate =datetime.valueof(historyLine.get('CreatedDate')).format();
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
                tempHistory.who = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            else {
                tempHistory.theDate = '';
                tempHistory.who = '';
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            prevDate = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate'));

            // Get the field label
            String fieldLabel = Core_GenericHistoryComponentController.returnFieldLabel(String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')));

            // Set the Action value
            if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')) == 'created') {    // on Creation
                tempHistory.action = 'Created.';
            }
            else if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && historyLine.get('newValue') ==null) { // when deleting a value from a field
                // Format the Date and if there's an error, catch it and re
                try {
                    tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format() + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                } catch (Exception e){
                    tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' +String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')) + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                }
            }
            else {  // all other scenarios
                String fromText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null) {
                    try {
                        fromText = ' from ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        fromText = ' from ' + String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue'));
                    }
                }

                String toText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('newValue') != null) {
                    try {
                        toText = Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).format();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        toText = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue'));
                    }
                }
                if (toText != ''){
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>' + fromText + ' to <b>' + toText + '</b>.';
                }
                else {
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel;
                }
            }

            // Add to the list
            objectHistory.add(tempHistory);
        }
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
 public class Core_GenericHistoryComponentCntl_Test{
       static testMethod void testHistoryController2() {


         Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 03-25-2015', BillingStreet = '123 Fake St',
                                   BillingCity = 'Springfield', BillingState = 'IL', BillingCountry = 'USA',
                                   BillingPostalCode = '12345',);
         insert acct;
                 acct.Name='Updated Name';
                 update acct;

        Test.startTest();

    Core_GenericHistoryComponentCntl_Test accHistClass = new Core_GenericHistoryComponentCntl_Test();


    AccountHistory[] accHist = accHistClass.retrieveAccountHistory(acct.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEQuals(1, accHist.size());   

         Core_GenericHistoryComponentController His= new Core_GenericHistoryComponentController();
             His.recordLimit=20;
              His.myObject=acct;

                 His.getObjectHistory();

    }



    public AccountHistory[] retrieveAccountHistory(Id accountId){
     List<AccountHistory> ah;
     if(Test.isRunningTest()){  //if TEST, create dummy AccountHistory
         ah = new List<AccountHistory>{}; //OldValue, NewValue not writeable
         ah.add(new AccountHistory(AccountId=accountId, Field='Name'));
     }
     else 
         ah=  [Select AccountId, Field, OldValue, NewValue from AccountHistory where AccountId = :accountId];


     return ah;
    }
       }
```

Comment: Testing things that rely on history objects is hard. Looking into `Test.loadData()` might be worthwhile, though I forget if it can help in this situation or not. It might be easier to design a class to sit in-between your code (that uses history data) and the history objects themselves.

Comment: This can't be done; You need to create a collection of `ProxyHistoryObject` that a selector class populates with the SOQL results and then mock the `ProxyHistoryObject(s)` in the testmethod using dependency injection; The JSON.deserialize method will not work for `OldValue` and `NewValue`